# How to connect a camera to a Windows PC for charging only?

Tags: windows, usb, battery, power, camera

I have a Xiaomi camera and I want to connect it to Windows PC for charging, but I want the camera to be turned on. There is a feature that you can have the camera enabled without battery - when the USB is connected to power source (e.g. a portable power bank). I want to achieve the same by connecting it to PC, but as soon as I connect it and turn it on, the camera is put into file transfer mode - recognized as a USB device by Windows. I want to bypass this and connect it to the PC for a power source only.

Comment: Have you tried to disconnect it inside windows, but keep the camera plugged in? When you use the USB device option "safely remove" inside windows, some devices are put into charging mode only afterwards.

Comment: @MarekRost when I eject in in explorer, camera does not react and LED indicate that it is still in 'connected to PC' mode. when I turn it off and turn on again without removing cable - it is recognised by windows again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an USB cable that is for charging only (no data pins).

If you can't find one, just open up any compatible USB cable, cut the green and white and you have yourself a power-only cable. Either that or cover the 2 middle pins with a small plastic so they don't make actual contact.